# Write the vector field such that its integral curves are the meridians of $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I have problems in  writing down a vector field $X$ on the sphere $S^2$ such that the integral curves of $X$ are the meridians of $S^2$.

I proceed in this way.

I consider this parametrisation of $S^2$: $$ x=\cos(\varphi) \cos(\alpha),$$$$ y=\cos(\varphi) \sin(\alpha), $$ $$ z=\sin(\varphi) .$$

A meridian is a curve:
$$\sigma(t)=(\sigma_1(t),\sigma_2(t),\sigma_3(t)) =(\cos(\varphi+t) \cos(\alpha),\cos(\varphi+t) \sin(\alpha),\sin(\varphi+t)).$$

Then I have that:
$$\dot\sigma_1(t)=\cos(\alpha)\sin(\varphi+t)$$
$$\dot\sigma_2(t)=-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\varphi+t)$$
$$\dot\sigma_1(t)=\cos(\varphi+t)$$

Now, in order to find the components of the vector field, should I calculate these derivates for $t=0$ ? In this way is the vector field written in respect to the basis $\partial x$, $\partial y$, $\partial z$?

My ideas are quite confused. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that `\cos` produces $\cos$ as opposed to `cos` which produces $cos$.

Comment: First of all, the vector field will only be defined on $S^2-\{(0,0,\pm1)\}$, right? Do you know how to work with local coordinates $(\phi,\alpha)$? Do you know what $\partial/\partial\alpha$ and $\partial/\partial\phi$ mean as vector fields?

Comment: @TedShifrin  Why do you exclude poles of sphere?

Comment: @TedShifrin They are a basis of the tangent space, am I right?

Comment: @TedShifrin I can write every vector field as a linear combination of the vector fields $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$

Comment: Well, you can do so away from the poles. @Evgeny: This is not a valid parametrization at the poles (and, in principle, one limits $0<\alpha<2\pi$, but that's artificial). So draw a picture of what these vector fields look like on the sphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin One is a vector tangent to the parallel and the other to the meridian

Comment: @Gloria: So then haven't you solved your original question?

Comment: @TedShifrin Ahh ok...Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @TedShifrin ah, you've just meant the problem with parameterization, now I understand :) but this parameterization still hints that not every vector field on this parameterization can be continued to a vector field on sphere, doesn't it?

Comment: @Evgeny: Two things. First of all, all the meridians go through the north and south pole, so you can't have a well-defined nonzero vector at the poles. If the vector field vanishes, the integral curves will be only portions of the meridians. Second, by the Hairy Ball Theorem, there can be *no* nowhere-vanishing vector field on the sphere.